# SML Function Argument Pattern Matching

Tags: functional-programming, logic, sml, smlnj

I am using pattern matching on argument passed to a function. The method works fine for "first level" matching so to say but any attempt to go deeper gives the error "**stdIn:282.5-291.77 Error: match redundant**"

example

```
fun nnf T = T
    | nnf F = F
    | nnf (LETTER(x)) = (LETTER(x))
    | nnf (NEG(x)) = (NEG(nnf x))
    | nnf (AND(x,y)) = (AND(nnf x, nnf y))
    | nnf (OR(x,y)) = (OR(nnf x, nnf y))
    | nnf (IMP(x,y)) = (OR(NEG(nnf x),(nnf y)))
    | nnf (NEG(NEG(LETTER(x)))) = (LETTER(x))
    | nnf (NEG(AND(LETTER(x),LETTER(y)))) = (OR(NEG(LETTER(x)),NEG(LETTER(y))))
    | nnf (NEG(OR(LETTER(x),LETTER(y)))) = (AND(NEG(LETTER(x)),NEG(LETTER(y))));
val nnf = fn : prop -> prop
```

the error i get is

```
stdIn:282.5-291.77 Error: match redundant
          T => ...
          F => ...
          LETTER x => ...
          NEG x => ...
          AND (x,y) => ...
          OR (x,y) => ...
          IMP (x,y) => ...
    -->   NEG (NEG (LETTER x)) => ...
    -->   NEG (AND (LETTER x,LETTER y)) => ...
    -->   NEG (OR (LETTER x,LETTER y)) => ...
```

so SML is saying that the last 3 clauses in the function definition are the same since they all begin with "(NEG(..." even though what follows is different.

how do i overcome this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case `NEG(x)` already covers any possible case involving outermost `NEG`, so the others are never reached. Depending on what you actually want to achieve, either remove that case, or move it after the more specific ones (cases are tried in order).